# what is complexity of my code in big-o notation

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

There is a code and i'm curious about the algorithmic complexity of this code in the big-o notation.

```
def listsum(numList):
   if len(numList) == 1:
        return numList[0]
   else:
        return numList[0] + listsum(numList[1:])
```

Comment: This might help: see [Calculating Big O](https://hackernoon.com/big-o-for-beginners-622a64760e2)

Answer (score 0):

Slicing an array is linear in the size of the slice, so the recurrence relation is

```
T(0) = 1
T(n) = T(n-1) + n
```

which has the asymptotic solution

```
T(n) ∈ Θ(n^2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Bro - after a while considered the complexity is O ( n*(n+1)/2 ). Explanation: Recursive operations on 1D array can be visualized like building triangular numbers because those are tiangular numbers. Jarmod was right my previous answer was wrong

Comment: Because of series of recursive returns

Comment: jarmod this is not addressed to you, so your comment about 'bro' is inappropriate